# AWS Registering Multiple Target Groups with a ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-ecs

I need to create multiple target groups for an ECS service. Does anyone have an example of how I can do this via AWS CLI or API?
As it is a recent functionality I have not found many examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively [new feature at ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/amazon-ecs-services-now-support-multiple-load-balancer-target-groups/), I have not had the opportunity to test it in a project but just reading the documentation, it looks like pretty straight forward: Just add multiple load balancer (target groups) definitions inside the service. For example, if you're using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_service.html#load_balancer-1), just add multiple `load_balancer` blocks:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "my_service" {
  name            = "my_service"
  cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.foo.id}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.my_task.arn}"
  ... # other arguments


  ordered_placement_strategy {
    ...
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.one.arn}"
    container_name   = "my_container_name"
    container_port   = 1234
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.two.arn}"
    container_name   = "my_container_name"
    container_port   = 4321
  }
}
```